# How to join this 3 tables using SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have some tables

```
Songs
id   title       year   performer    genre
1    Lagu Satu   2010   Band Satu    Rock
2    Lagu Dua    2010   Band Dua     Metal
3    Lagu Tiga   2011   Band Tiga    Metal
4    Lagu Empat  2012   Band Empat   Rock
5    Lagu Lima   2013   Band Lima    Metal


Users
id   username   password   fullname
1    user1      user1      User Satu
2    user2      user2      User Dua
3    user3      user3      User Tiga
4    user4      user4      User Empat
5    user5      user5      User Lima
6    user6      user6      User Enam


Playlists
id   name         owner
1    Lagu Rock    1
2    Lagu Metal   1
3    Mantap       1
4    Lagu Rock    2
5    Edan         2
6    Skuy Living  3

PlaylistSongs
id   playlist_id    song_id
 1   1              1
 2   1              4
 3   2              2
 4   2              3
 5   2              5
 6   3              4
 7   3              5
 8   3              2
 9   5              2
10   5              4
11   5              5
12   5              1


Collaborations
id   playlist_id    user_id
1    1              5
2    5              5
3    6              5
4    2              4
5    6              4
6    6              2
```

When I did this:

```
SELECT 
      playlists.id, 
      playlists.name, 
      users.username 
   FROM 
      playlists 
         JOIN collaborations 
            ON playlists.id = collaborations.playlist_id 
         JOIN users 
            ON users.id = playlists.owner 
   WHERE 
         playlists.owner = 2 
      OR collaborations.user_id = 2;
```

I got this:

```
id   name           username
5    Edan           user2
6    Skuy Living    user3
```

What I want is like this:

```
id   name           username
4    Lagu Rock      user2
5    Edan           user2
6    Skuy Living    user3
```

How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to S/O.  Please try not pasting images, but put sample data directly in the question.  You can copy/paste the data then align via spacing.  Ctrl+K formats as you can see here vs word-wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. The only thing you need to change is the `JOIN` ordering and turning `JOIN collaborations` to `LEFT JOIN collaborations`. Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, u.username
FROM playlists p 
 JOIN users u ON u.id = p.owner 
 LEFT JOIN collaborations c
            ON p.id = c.playlist_id 
 WHERE p.owner=2 OR c.user_id=2;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f893f31607fa37873ce42ffc19912a2d)